# custom <li> malposition when long text in it

Tags: html, css

I have a custom ordered list and the counter is set in :before of `li`. When the content in `li` is a single word longer than the width of line, a malposition will happen.

```css
ol {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  text-indent: -1.4em;
  list-style-position: inside;
  user-select: text;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

li:before {
  left: -36px;
  width: 30px;
  position: static;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(ol0) ". ";
  counter-increment: ol0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>111111111111111111111111321421421421421312111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111321421421321421421412412421412411123214214214214214213214214214213214124111111111111111111</li>
</ol>
```

The result will show that the counter is in the first line and the content is displayed in the second. What can I do to let them share the same line?

Comment: Share a screenshot. It will help us understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just position the list markers `absolute` and remove the negative `text-indent`.

```css
ol {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  list-style-position: inside;
  user-select: text;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

li::before {
  left: -36px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(ol0) ". ";
  counter-increment: ol0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>111111111111111111111111321421421421421312111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111321421421321421421412412421412411123214214214214214213214214214213214124111111111111111111</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the li:before position to 'absolute' does the trick:

```css
ol {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  text-indent: -1.4em;
  list-style-position: inside;
  user-select: text;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

li:before {
  left: -36px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(ol0) ". ";
  counter-increment: ol0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>111111111111111111111111321421421421421312111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111321421421321421421412412421412411123214214214214214213214214214213214124111111111111111111</li>
</ol>
```